# Get post meta in enqueued js file

Tags: php, javascript

I am writing a plugin in which I have a js file. I enqueue it with wp_enqueue_script. In this file I have some functions. The functions are triggered by an onclick event of a button. The button is located on edit post page. Now I need those functions to get post meta of the edited post, modify and save.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can send variables to your script with [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );

global $post;
$my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', true );

$array = array( 
    'my_meta' => $my_meta
);

wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $array );
```

You can then use the var in your script like:

```
object_name.my_meta
```

Comment: Might want to check `is_singular` first before using the global post object, or it won't work like you expect.  Also, `get_queried_object_id`:  `$meta = get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'my_meta', true);`. No need for `global $post`.

Comment: This is a very good idea, but I need then to modify the variable in js file and update it. Any idea how?

Comment: [AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: You are probably right, but I am js newbe so an example would be useful.